# FreeBSD rc.conf not adding lagg group to bridge on system start up or service restart

Tags: networking, freebsd, bridge, bonding

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here. I have the following configuration in my `/etc/rc.conf` on my (personal) server.

```
cloned_interfaces="bridge0 lagg0"
ifconfig_igb0="up"
ifconfig_igb1="up"
ifconfig_lagg0="laggproto loadbalance laggport igb0 laggport igb1 up"
ifconfig_bridge0="addm lagg0"
ifconfig_bridge0="inet 172.16.0.11 netmask 255.255.255.0 up"
defaultrouter="172.16.0.1"
```

When trigger a `service netif restart` to test the new configuration the system brings up the interfaces and set the IP address to bridge as it should. The only thing that doesn't work is the bridge doesn't add the lagg group to the bridge.

Any ideas on what could be wrong? I am running FreeBSD 12.0-RELEASE-p7. I feel like I my configuration should work. The bridge will accept the lagg group if I add it manually with `addm lagg0` but it will not do it automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have overwritten the value of the `ifconfig_bridge0` by using:

```
ifconfig_bridge0="addm lagg0"
ifconfig_bridge0="inet 172.16.0.11 netmask 255.255.255.0 up"
```

Either convert it into a single line:

```
ifconfig_bridge0="inet 172.16.0.11 netmask 255.255.255.0 addm lagg0"
```

*I don't think you need to `up` the bridge interface.*

Or use an append syntax:

```
ifconfig_bridge0="inet 172.16.0.11 netmask 255.255.255.0 up"
ifconfig_bridge0="$ifconfig_bridge0 addm lagg0"
```

*I don't know if the order is significant, but I add the member interfaces last.*

Comment: The second code block worked perfect. Not sure why but when I did the command is reverse order (add int, then assign IP) the bridge wouldn't work but now it does.